# Still have access to Google account, but lost two factor authentication device

Tags: gmail, multi-factor-auth

Immigrated, forgot to turn off two factor authentication, changed SIM. Still have access to my account via laptop, and phone. All working fine. Got new phone. When attempting to use a SMS sent to authenticate: "Oh yeah I forgot to remove it" - simple I have still access via laptop so I can log onto account and remove two factor.

No, no, no I can't. To get to that level of security I need two factor authentication to be working.

I have the alternate rescue email set correctly, but not alternate mobile and no saved recovery codes.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official help topic](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185834?hl=en#phone) you should be able to if it's a trusted device. If you don't have a trusted device available you should fill out the recovery form. Again further details are in the FAQ.

An alternative would be to get back the old SIM assuming it was still usable.

If neither of the options from the FAQ is available and you're not able to get back the old SIM/number. You're probably out of luck.